# Best Practices for using SQL Server CE in a multi-threaded app (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

Are there any best practices for using SQL Server CE in a multi-threaded application?

I'll get this started

Datacontexts are not threadsafe

I think there must be more problems because I still get cross thread failures in my application such as

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>   Message=The operation cannot be performed because an operation on another thread has not been completed.
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.CheckThreadId()
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.BootUser(Int32
>   userIndex)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser
>   user)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object
>   lastResult, Boolean isCompiledQuery)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query,
>   QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[]
>   userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Boolean
>   isCompiledQuery)
>   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query)
>   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   at App.ViewModel.LoadData(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
>   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
>   at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRun(Object argument)
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context(Object
>   state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
>   at System.Threading.Timer.ring()

Comment: Are you able to supply a code fragment? As a general rule, don't create SQL CE transactions in one thread and use them in another.

Comment: It's a bit complex for a code fragment, which is why I'm asking about best practices. I'm assuming I've made a hash of my data access design so I want to re-wrok it based on some tried and tested rules/ideas

Comment: Never share a DataContext cross thread - but it is hard to advise unless you share some code!

Comment: For windows phone, this article is really great. http://queconejo.wordpress.com/2011/09/04/windows-phone-mango-and-concurrent-database-access/